# Div extends too far down the page

Tags: css, html

Ok, here is the problem:

I have a left side menu that will not size correctly to the page. If the content does not have to scroll the footer should be at the bottom and the menu div should extend down to touch the footer. I tried the sticky footer trick or w/e it is called...but with no luck with the menu.

Here is my CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #999966 url(bgbottom.png);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: bottom;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

a {
    color: #29211D;
}
h2 {

    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.head {

    background-image: url(bg.jpg);
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #29211D;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 185px;
}

.nav {

    background-color: #29211D;
    width: 150px;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    height: auto !important;
    min-height: 100%;
    font-size: 14px;    
    float: left;
}

.content {

    font-size: 14px;
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    height: auto !important;
    min-height: 70%;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 2px #666 solid;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-top: 1%;
}   

.footer {

    background-image: url(bg.jpg);
    border-top: #29211D solid 3px;
    border-bottom: #29211D solid 3px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;

}
```

here is the site: http://www.pomaceaproject.org/dev/test.asp

Comment: Actually, I wonder if doing a -bannersizepx margin would fix this...?

Comment: Update: doing that did not work...

Comment: I'm not understanding what is your problem!

Comment: 70% should be 100% sorry.. was editing  code had copied the wrong one! :) Fixed now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do, you want the navigation section to touch the bottom of the footer? If so, that is a simple change:

Change the min-height property of your .nav class from `min-height: 70%;` to `min-height: 100%;`

[Demo (obviously without all the pictures on it)](http://jsfiddle.net/YgLrt/)

**Current .css:**

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #999966 url(bgbottom.png);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: bottom;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

a {
    color: #29211D;
}
h2 {

    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.head {

    background-image: url(bg.jpg);
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #29211D;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 185px;
}

.nav {

    background-color: #29211D;
    width: 150px;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    height: auto !important;
    min-height: 73%;
    font-size: 14px;    
    float: left;
    overflow: auto;

}

.content {

    font-size: 14px;
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
    height: auto !important;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 2px #666 solid;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-top: 1%;
}   

.footer {

    background-color: #999966; /* Can probably be removed as you will have a background image */
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background-image: url(bg.jpg);
    border-top: #29211D solid 3px;
    border-bottom: #29211D solid 3px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    z-index: 100;   /* Since it is will need to overlay the background of the navigation behind it */
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Sorry it was 100%. But when I put 100% it goes way past the bottom of the page. :( Almost like the banner is causing this. So I tried doing a bottom -185px margin to see if that would fix it. No good. :( Thanks though.

Comment: I'll keep searching :) - is the issue that when the page has a vertical scroll-bar that the navigation portion doesn't reach the footer?

Comment: Yes. In firefox atm the menu side bar goes down way too far causingthe scroll-bar to come up when it is unnecessary..but if the content did scroll that far I would want the menu bar to go all the way down to the footer. Well I want it to always go down to the footer.

Comment: Update: it only does what I describe in firefox. Looks fine in IE.

Comment: I can't seem to notice a difference between the browsers using the current source (assuming that you are updating the site in the question during this time).

Comment: It might be your resolution... ill take a screen shot of what i'm seeing  - - - http://img340.imageshack.us/img340/4953/21250027.jpg

Comment: 1920x1080 here - It can tend to skew things for some :)

Comment: Although, is the menu touching the footer on your res? (i hope so! ><)

Comment: On 1920x1080, the menu goes all the way to the footer :)

Comment: Ah, any ideas on why it does that in firefox at a smaller rez? :\

Comment: Not sure - I have an idea that might work. I'll give it a shot in a second, and just to reiterate you are trying to have no scroll-bar if there does not need to be one right?

Comment: Right, like in my screenshot the footer should be closer to the content area (white box) with a little spacing in between it, but def. not that far down the page. :P

Comment: Adding the .css that I was working with - I played with the positioning of the footer etc. (Made it absolute to stick at the bottom of the page) I think it's getting close, you will just have to play with it some - as my workday is over here. I'll check it tomorrow if you still need help :)